# Does the P value need to be "back- transformed" after logging one variable in Regression analyse?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, p-value, nonparametric, logarithm

I have a data series, sediment concentration in water Vs Time. The data is not normal but I want to use regression and so have logged the sediment concentration (log10(x)). The residual and fit to model is now much better.

I want to use the P value and r squared values from the logged regression output. Do these need to be transformed back using e^x ?

Thanks.

[edit] This is being carried out in Excel using the data analysis tool: Picture linked here :
[Excel output from log10concentration vS Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duDh9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Consider if $p=0.05$. Then $e^p=1.05>1$, which is not a meaningful p-value.

In fact, raising any positive value (such as $e$) to any positive number (such as a p-value or $R^2$) results in a number greater than $1$.

Neither $R^2$ nor $p$ should exceed $1$.

Comment: Thank you! So I am able to use the values directly from the logged output ?

Comment: Further, if your transformation is a base-ten logarithm, the natural “transformation back” would be $10^x$, not $e^x$.

Comment: @Rose I would want to know more about what you’re doing before I advise much more than what I wrote. Perhaps consider posting a new question that discusses your problem and goals.